# Odoo pdf report, how to show foreach loop index

Tags: odoo-15

How can I show the index number of t-foreach look? I want to show index of each line in the pdf report

```
<t t-set="lines" t-value="delivery.mapped('delivery_line_ids')"/>
   <tr t-foreach="lines" t-as="line">
      <span t-field="???????"/> 
   </tr>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the name passed via `t-as`, `foreach` provides a few other variables for various data points listed in the Odoo qweb templates [loops](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#loops) section.

You can access the current iteration index using `$line_index` variable (the first item of the iteration has index `0`)